# How to export string array in pqsl to CSV from Rails 4.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv

I need export some records with `string array` from `postgres 9.3` to `CSV`, and then import the `CSV` back to `postgres` table again in Rails 4.2 app. When I import the `CSV` file back to `psql` table, it throws out error about `string array` fields. Apparently the `string array` in `CSV` exported is not recognizable by `postgres`.
[image][image]

The field `measure_choices`  of `string array` is defined in Rails migrate file as:

```
t.string    :measure_choices, array: true, default: []
```

It is exported to `CSV` using standard `Ruby CSV` library:

```
CSV.generate do |csv|
  row = Array.new
  #making row.
  row << rails_obj.measure_choices
  ....
  csv << row
end
```

I notice there are a few differences between `postgres` and `Rails` about `string array` representing. Empty array is {} in psql and [] in rails. There is no double quote for a string in psql `string array`, and Rails seems has the double quote.

What's right way to export psql to CSV which is in right format for psql importing?

UPDATE:
Following are 2 CSV file exported from `psql` command line and `Rails` respectively.

`PSQL Way`:

[image]

`RAILS Way`:

[image]

The double quote and [] in `CSV` exported by Rails causes problem when importing back to psql table.

Comment: is there any chance you can use psql `\copy` or sql `copy` for it?

Comment: `Vao Tsun`, not sure how I can use \copy in Rails code. Probably not. I used \copy in psql command line to export csv.

Comment: I meant you to use it for import as well. Why ruby - not psql?